# How to resolve TypingErrors when the property of an ak.Array subclass relies on Numba-compiled functions?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, awkward-array

I've perused the docs and demo notebooks in the awkward1 repo (and it's entirely possible I missed something obvious), but I've strayed into unfamiliar territory and would like some help.

Suppose I have points in a polar coordinate frame that I provide to users as an array of records using the awkward1 library. Some users may prefer to work with the points in a Cartesian coordinate frame, so I can accommodate them by adding behaviors, and the following example works.

```py
import awkward1 as ak
import numpy as np


class Polar2Cartesian(object):
    """Mixin class to convert from polar to Cartesian."""
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.r * np.cos(self.theta)

    # And similarly for y, but this is just an example


# Register the behaviors with awkward
class Point(ak.Record, Polar2Cartesian):
    pass

class PointArray(ak.Array, Polar2Cartesian):
    pass

ak.behavior['Point'] = Point
ak.behavior['*', 'Point'] = PointArray

# Define the points
r = np.array([2.53, 0.29, 3.18])
theta = np.array([np.pi/4, np.pi, -np.pi/3])
points = ak.zip({'r': r, 'theta': theta}, with_name='Point')

# x-component of the first point
points[0].x == r[0] * np.cos(theta[0]) # True

# x-components of all points
points.x == r * np.cos(theta) # <Array [True, True, True] type='3 * bool'>
```

Now suppose the conversion must use a Numba-compiled function. I've defined one in the following example, but in principle it could come from a third-party library over which I have no control. The following works for individual records, but raises a TypingError over the array of records.

```py
import awkward1 as ak
import numba as nb
import numpy as np


@nb.njit
def cos(x):
    """A contrived example appears."""
    return np.cos(x)

class Polar2Cartesian(object):
    """Mixin class to convert from polar to Cartesian."""
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.r * cos(self.theta) # uses jitted function here

    # And similarly for y, but this is just an example

# Define and register the behaviors like before, and create
# the same array of Points as in the previous example

# This still works
points[0].x == r[0] * np.cos(theta[0]) # True

# This now raises a TypingError
points.x == r * np.cos(theta)
```

Parsing the traceback reveals the reason for the TypingError:

> TypingError: can't resolve ufunc cos for types (awkward1.ArrayView(awkward1.NumpyArrayType(array(float64, 1d, A), none, {}), None, ()),)

That's fair, as it would be unreasonable to expect Numba to know how to use this type without help from the developer.

A workaround I have found is to call `np.asarray()` within the definition of `Polar2Cartesian.x`, i.e. `cos(np.asarray(self.theta))`. Although `cos` returns a NumPy array, `Polar2Cartesian.x` ends up becoming an awkward Array due to the subsequent multiplication with `self.r`. In general, one could convert the return value to an awkward record or array as needed.

But is this solution "awkward1-approved", or should I be going the route where I provide typer and lower functions for theta and x as additional behaviors? If the latter, could someone walk me through how to correctly write the typer and lower functions?

At this point, I wonder if the scope of my question title is too broad. If someone has a better suggestion, please let me know.